# Removing ubuntu 12.04 from triple boot of windows 7 , 8 and ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, windows-7, windows-8, uninstall

so i had a dual boot PC with windows 7 and 8 with 5 partitons , i shrinked one partition and left 50 gb of space unallocated using disk mangaement of windows 7 while installing ubuntu it gave me an option to install ubuntu alongside windows 8 so i clicked next and it installed automatically without choosing any partition , everything is fine but now i want to uninstall ubuntu but i dont know which partition it has installed when i open disk management it shows an unnamed drive of 50 gb which is mostly free, please guide in uninstalling ubuntu 12.04 , thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Take windows 8 dvd. Boot with it. Then run a repair.

After reboot you should be prompted with windows 8 bootloader.

Now goto disk manager and delete the partition that is marked as "unknown file system". It should be side by side of windows 8 partition. You can merge the free space after deleting to adjacent driver or create a new one.

Comment: i had a doubt,if some part of the grub stored in ubuntu partition means why we run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` command to install grub on the first disk.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Just to add GRUB to master boot record of the disk (not paritition, partitions are sda1, sda2 etc). MBR doesn't hold whole GRUB or Windows Bootloader because of size constraints. It is used to point from where to load the bootloader. It is called as stage 1, stage 2 etc.See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB#Operation. The final piece is kept in /boot/grub. So if you erase the /boot partition (which can be in ubuntu partition as well) GRUB will never load and will stuck in `GRUB>` prmpt

Answer (score 0):

Usually ubuntu must be installed on ext4 partition.You can't access this ext4 partition on Windows normally.So to delete the Ubuntu partition or to uninstall ubuntu follow the below steps,

- Boot Ubuntu live disk and then open gparted.
- Locate and format the partition where ubuntu is installed to ntfs filesystem.
- Then open up the terminal and run `sudo update-grub` command.

Comment: Just want to confirm.. don't you need windows mbr to be restored? I never tried in this way. Will GRUB be still functional after you delete ubuntu partition? Because some part of GRUB will be stored in that ubuntu partition. Once you delete that you should be stuck in "GRUB" prompt. I am not sure that is why I have not voted down.